# How do I declare a member object of custom type and initialize afterwards in C++?

Tags: c++, object, types, initialization, member

The following code works when run at [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh):

```
#include <iostream>

class B{
    public:
        B(int i);
        int i;
};

B::B(int i) {
    this->i = i;
}

class A{
    public:
        A(B *b);
        B *b;
};

A::A(B *b) {
    this->b = b;
}


int main()
{
  B b(8);
  A a(&b);
  std::cout << a.b->i;
}
```

It creates an object of type `B` and stores a pointer in an object of type `A`.
What I want to do is to only pass the integer (8 in this case) and create and store the full object in `a` without creating an intermediate object.

But when I try to declare a object of type B (not just a pointer) inside A, I get a `no matching function for call to 'B::B()`error.

This is the approach I tried, which doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
// B i not changed
class B{
    public:
        B(int i);
        int i;
};

B::B(int i) {
    this->i = i;
}

class A{
    public:
        A(int i);
        B b;
};

A::A(int i) {
    this->b(i); //initialize
}


int main()
{
  A a(8);
  std::cout << a.b->i;
}
```

Why do I get a "no matching function" error when declaring a `B b;` variable instead of a pointer `B *b;`?
Is my approach `this->b(i);` to initialize a member after declaration correct?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `type 'B' is not a direct base of 'A'`

Comment: Re: "It creates an object of type `B` and stores a reference in an object of type `A`" there are no **references** here. The original code stores a **pointer** inside the `A` object.

Comment: @uzumaki Oops, consider that a typo. `A::A(int i) : b(i) {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class `B` does not provide a constructor taking no arguments (the implicitly defined default constructor gets deleted once you declare any other constructor). 
When you define another class `A` with a data member of type `class B`, the system cannot initialize this data member unless you explicitly define which constructor of `B` with which arguments should be used.

You can overcome this by...

1. Call the constructor of `b` in an member-initializer list of `A`'s constructor, i.e. `A::A(int i) : b(i) {}`
2. Default-Initialize data member `b` when defining it, i.e. in `A`, write `B b = B(1)`;
3. Define a (user-defined) default constructor in `B`, e.g. `B() : i(0) {}`
4. Define a default value in the (sole) constructor of `B`, e.g. `B(int i=0)`

I'd prefer option 1; Options 2..4 are listed just for completeness.

Note that any code, regardless which, in the body of a constructor is not considered as "data member initialization".

Comment: @grek40: Right, noted it in the question accordingly.